# Use the new keyword if hiding was intended - ContextMenu XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, warnings, contextmenu

I am developing a WPF application and I have several warnings of this type which I cant get rid of.

The warnings say that:

Warning 49  'Suite.Module.SlopeExperiment.Views.OverviewSteadyStateChartView.ContextMenu' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ContextMenu'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

When i double click the warning in Visual Studio i am redirected to this XAML code:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Export as image" Click="ExportAsImageClick"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.ContextMenu>
```

Any ideas of how to get rid of this warning?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Use some other value for `x:Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding x:Name with Different value and

or

try below

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.ContextMenu x:Name="ctxmenu"> 
        <MenuItem Header="Export as image" Click="ExportAsImageClick"/>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: In my case, I was able to remove the Name attribute altogether (which I wasn't referencing anyway), and this removed the compiler warning.